# fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly when running git push

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, git-push

I created a react project and did not know that I was supposed to put node_modules into the .gitignore file. I committed node_modules changes to git and now when I try to pull and push commits from and to "origin/main", I get the following error:

```
error: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Writing objects: 100% (256/256), 102.30 MiB | 7.64 MiB/s, done.
Total 256 (delta 101), reused 228 (delta 81), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have now created a .gitignore file and added node_modules to it, but I still cannot push origin to Github.

Comment: Why would you commit node_modules? Thats usually thousands of files! That's why package management exists, so somebody else can install the modules locally again and you don't have to commit them! Also, your remote hung up, it's a 500 HTTP error, not a git error. Your git server ain't working. There is not enough information to help any more, but maybe it's good you didm't get to commit a ridiculous amount of files.